# Different Results on Keras and TensorFlow lite

Tags: tensorflow-lite

I am using TensorFlow lite version for the model evaluation.
While running on Keras, I am getting the different results on running TensorFlow lite.

Could you please help me understanding what is wrong in my work.

**Code running using Keras:**

```
data_df = pd.read_csv('core3_input_withHeader.csv')

feature_list = ['core3_SQst', 'core3_headPress', 'core3_rodPress']
channels = []
for feature in feature_list:
    channels.append(data_df.loc[:, data_df.columns.str.contains(feature)])
input_array = np.stack([channels[0].values.squeeze(), channels[1].values.squeeze(), channels[2].values.squeeze()], axis=1)
input_array_norm = input_array[np.newaxis,:,:]

autoencoder = keras.models.load_model('models/core3_ac_model.h5')
encoder = keras.models.Model(inputs= autoencoder.input, outputs = autoencoder.get_layer('bottleneck').output)
encoded_feat_full = encoder.predict(input_array_norm)
print(encoded_feat_full)
```

> Results: [[-0.05779254 -0.13797456  0.42000926 -0.16879612 -0.26408887
>   -0.7427746
>      0.393916   -0.69853663  0.6064893   0.7713756  -0.26022637  1.2051586
>      0.5575749  -0.12699515 -0.6362914  -0.1943332   0.13275155  0.10403969   -0.614455   -0.5115924   0.08213274  0.38980693 -0.394821   -0.39467907
>      0.9681511   0.05354612 -0.4930368  -0.42177224 -0.4795676  -0.21956956   -0.04954213 -0.33019006]]

**While running on tensorflow Lite:**
*I already converted my model to tflite version using the following command:*

```
tflite_convert --keras_model_file=/home/superuser/tico_model/core3_ac_model.h5 --output_file=/home/superuser/tico_model/tf_tico_model.tflite
```

Which given me the model tf_tico_model.tflite

```
import tensorflow as tf
import tensorflow.keras as keras
print(tf.version.VERSION)
# 2.0.0-rc2

import numpy as np
import pandas as pd
from tflite_runtime.interpreter import Interpreter

data_df = pd.read_csv('core3_input_withHeader.csv')
feature_list = ['core3_SQst', 'core3_headPress', 'core3_rodPress']

channels = []
for feature in feature_list:
    channels.append(data_df.loc[:, data_df.columns.str.contains(feature)])

input_array = np.stack([channels[0].values.squeeze(), channels[1].values.squeeze(), channels[2].values.squeeze()], axis=1)
input_array_norm = input_array[np.newaxis,:,:]
input_data = np.array(input_array_norm, dtype=np.float32)

#run the inference
autoencoder = tf.lite.Interpreter(model_path="./tf_tico_model.tflite")
autoencoder.allocate_tensors()

# at Index:1 the model input and 9 is output
autoencoder.set_tensor(1, input_data)
autoencoder.invoke()
output_data = autoencoder.get_tensor(9)
print(output_data)
```

> INFO: Initialized TensorFlow Lite runtime. [[ 0.76454383 -0.70871294
>   -0.7592763   0.7502928  -0.75859773 -0.75297236
>      0.7334     -0.7616406  -0.7565583   0.77855337 -0.74473566 -0.73970836
>      0.8058165  -0.74315614 -0.7622459   0.79716206 -0.73603505 -0.72557694
>      0.7875527  -0.7533992  -0.7004597   0.77682453 -0.7581499  -0.6704023
>      0.7861713  -0.73904926 -0.6299191   0.775358   -0.7538745  -0.5752099
>      0.7788005  -0.747791  ]]

I am not able to find, what wrong with this?

Could you please help me.

Thanks 
Kind Regards
Arun

Comment: Did you get any explanation on those differences ?

Comment: Not yet, I didn't find any solution..